# Why is the mean speed of a gaseous molecule $\sqrt{\frac{8RT}{\pi M}}$?

Tags: kinetic-theory

I was able to derive the formula for root-mean-squared speed of a molecule, using a basic method taught at school. However, in my textbook, there's a point that:

> It can be shown that $\bar v = \sqrt{\frac{8RT}{\pi M}}$

where $R = 8.314\text{ J mol}^{-1}\text{ K}^{-1}$, T = Absolute temperature, and M = Molar mass of given gas.

I was unable to prove this. I am aware of the Maxwell-Boltzmann speed distribution curve, but haven't learnt it in detail. Can this be derived from that? Are there other methods of deriving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track: you do indeed need to work out $v_{rms}$ from the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. There are no other methods, because, by definition, you compute a mean with respect to a probability distribution describing the underlying population, so the pdf has to come in somewhere.

The MB distribution comes from (1) the [Boltzmann Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution), justified by the analysis of the [Canonical Ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_ensemble), and, to apply this distribution, you also need to know what degeneracy function aka *density of states* $g(E) $ is - with each particle's energy given by $m\,v^2/2$, the number of possible states in a narrow velocity range around velocity $v$ is proportional to the volume of a spherical shell, *i.e.* proportional to $v^2$. So when we work out the Boltzmann distribution for the velocities, we get $p(E)\propto g(E) \exp(-E/(k\,T)) = v^2 e^{-\frac{m\,v^2}{2\,k\,T}}$, which last function is proportional to the Maxwell-Boltzman distribution $p_{MB}(v)$.

Now all you need to do is find the correct normalization constant to make $\int_0^\infty p_{MB}(v)\,\mathrm{d} v = 1$ (or look up the normalized distribution) and then work out the mean square velocity  $\int_0^\infty\,v^2\, p_{MB}(v)\,\mathrm{d} v$ and you're there.

You will also need to convert the Boltzmann constant $k$ to molar gas constant $R=N_A\,k$.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make it clear earlier, I wanted to derive $v_{mean}$ not $v_{rms}$. I believe you'll edit that in, as the method you say is for $v_{mean}$. +1 Thanks!

Comment: @AbhigyanC The method will work for any statistic. So, with the normalized distribution, calculate $\int_0^\infty\,v\,p_{MB}(v)\,\mathrm{d} v$.